# why dotnet.exe is terminated under IIS

Tags: asp.net-core

## Introduction

I do have WebApi on.Net Core 1.1 & simple test application executing some scenario with calls to my API in multiple threads. Web API is hosted under IIS  on WS 2012 R2.

## Problem

When I do start my test application with 20 threads in 20-30s test application begin to receive 401 error from the server. After some investigation, I've noticed that dotnet.exe process is suddenly terminated & restarted on the server on high load.
There is no information neither in my logs nor in Windows event log (only one from IIS AspNetCore Module about starting new process: `Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/DEFAULT WEB SITE' started process '10248' successfully and is listening on port '23570'`)

I've tried to reproduce this on my machine without any success - this does not happen when my API is hosted in IIS Express from VS.

## Question

What may be the reason?